# Как не пропустить прерывание?

Tags: архитектура, прерывания

Читать из переменных, изменяемых в прерываниях не безопасно. Поэтому я полагаю, что перед чтением, нужно маскировать прерывание, которые изменяет эту переменную. Что произойдет, если прерывание произойдет во время того, когда оно замаскированно ? Оно будет обработано позже ? Или это зависит от архитектуры ?

Comment: Определенно стоит смотреть руководства по конкретной железеке. Я думаю что зависит от архитектуры.